# expressjs with bodyParser giving array of numbers as array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, express, body-parser

Somehow I realized that when I pass array of numbers to the backend `expressjs` I I would get array of strings instead of numbers.

This is the ajax code for sending the data

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: this.url.ajax.send,
    data,
})
```

This is the values I have in frontend passing to backend

```
const data = {
  "type": [
    1,
    2
  ],
  "to": [
    0
  ],
  "message": "testing message here"
}
```

this is what I get in my backend `req.body`

```
{ type: [ '1', '2' ],
  to: [ '0' ],
  message: 'testing message here' }
```

I do have `bodyParser` setup like such

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 2000000,  // too many parameter if not set
    limit: 1024 * 1024 * 10  // entity too large if not set
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 2000000,  // too many parameter if not set
    limit: 1024 * 1024 * 10  // entity too large if not set
}));
```

Is this normal or any way I can fix it?

EDIT: This is an image I see from network tab in chrome's inspect tool
[image]

Comment: can you show how are you sending the data?

Comment: Try making a similar request using Postman (or curl) to your backend and let me know if it still happens.

Comment: @MohammedAmirAnsari edited, a jquery ajax call

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta my bad, I did test with postman and with postman it was fine that backend reads as array of numbers. But what I posted above for `const data = ` is what I `console.log` the values right before `ajax` call though

Comment: @Dora don't console.log, check in the network request using browser's dev tools what is actually being sent to the backend.

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta I added an image of the data from the network request tab

Comment: Does it help if you send it as JSON instead? Maybe it can't tell the difference between a string and a number in the URL encoded data.

Comment: @lilezek already send it as json :| and using `post` instead of `get` with params or there is something I am missing >.<"

Answer (score 1):

parse the string to int with parseInt, example :

```js
let requestBody = {
  type: [ '1', '2' ],
  to: [ '0' ],
  message: 'testing message here'
}

requestBody.type = requestBody.type.map((arr) => {
  arr = parseInt(arr)
  return arr
})

requestBody.to = requestBody.to.map((arr) => {
  arr = parseInt(arr)
  return arr
})

console.log(requestBody)
```